# Unable to run images created by docker compose independently

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

I have following docker compose file. Which creates two images api and scheduler. api exposes end point and scheduler runs at a particular time.  Both images run fine when I use `docker-compose up` but 
when I try to run images independently by `docker run -itd --name api   api:latest` and 
`docker run  -itd --name schedule scheduler:latest` it does not run ok. In both cases it shows CMD as python3 in container. I am expecting it to run `CMD  ["gunicorn",  "--bind", "0.0.0.0:5000",  "run_api:application", "&"]` for api container.

```
``
version: '3'
services:
  api:
    container_name: api
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: ["gunicorn",  "--bind", "0.0.0.0:5000",  "run_api:application", "&"]
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    restart: always
    environment:
      - config=${config}
  scheduler:
    container_name: scheduler
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: ["sh", "-c", "python3 run_scheduler.py"]
    ports:
        - "80:80"
    restart: always
    environment:
      - config=${config}
``
```

Comment: Does your Dockerfile have a `CMD` line?  Both containers build the same image, so one of them will need to pass the command after the image name in `docker run`, in the same way this `docker-compose.yml` has a `command:` to override the image's `CMD`.

Comment: Dockerfile does not have any CMD.  I will try the mentioned option. Thanks David